# Java: drawImage cannot find my BufferedImage

Tags: java

**I have my BufferedImage properly set up, but my compiler is giving me the error that it cannot find the variable img.**

**Here is the code:**

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("spooky.gif");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
mt.addImage(img,1);

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300,this);
}
```

Here is Stackoverflow telling me that I need to add more details.

**The entire code is as follows:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Spooky extends Applet
{
Image scary, trumpet, walking;
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("spooky.gif");
MediaTracker mt;
AudioClip spoopy;
Graphics buffer;
Image offscreen;
Dimension dim;


public void init()
{
    setLayout(null);
    mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    url = getDocumentBase();
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    scary = getImage(url,"scary.gif");
    trumpet = getImage(url,"trumpet.gif");
    walking = getImage(url,"walking.gif");
    mt.addImage(img,1);
    mt.addImage(scary,1);
    mt.addImage(trumpet,1);
    mt.addImage(walking,1);
    try{
        mt.waitForAll();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){}
    spoopy = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"spoopy.wav");
    spoopy.loop();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300,this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the variable outside its scope.
The variable wasn't accessible because you declared and initialized the variable in the init function while you used it in the paint function.
Try the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Spooky extends Applet
{
Image scary, trumpet, walking;
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("spooky.gif");
MediaTracker mt;
AudioClip spoopy;
Graphics buffer;
Image offscreen;
Dimension dim;
BufferedImage img;

public void init()
{
    setLayout(null);
    mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    url = getDocumentBase();
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
    scary = getImage(url,"scary.gif");
    trumpet = getImage(url,"trumpet.gif");
    walking = getImage(url,"walking.gif");
    mt.addImage(img,1);
    mt.addImage(scary,1);
    mt.addImage(trumpet,1);
    mt.addImage(walking,1);
    try{
        mt.waitForAll();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){}
    spoopy = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"spoopy.wav");
    spoopy.loop();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300,this);
}
}
```

Comment: I get an error: "Unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" on img = ImageIO.read(url); I think it means I need to add an IOException somewhere.

Comment: Then you should put it in a try-catch block

Comment: Here is my new code, the image loads but it is supposed to be an animated gif, and it is frozen on the first frame as if it is a jpeg or png. The edit is there, it just needs to be peer-reviewed.

Comment: That should be a seperate question, ryan. This should be closed as it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;

public class Spooky extends Applet
{
Image scary, trumpet, walking;
MediaTracker mt;
AudioClip spoopy;
Graphics buffer;
Image offscreen;
Dimension dim;

public void init()
{
setLayout(null);
mt = new MediaTracker(this);


mt.addImage(scary,1);
mt.addImage(trumpet,1);
mt.addImage(walking,1);
spoopy = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"spoopy.wav");
spoopy.loop();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  try
{
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("spooky.gif");
    BufferedImage img;
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
    mt.addImage(img,1);
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300,this);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
}

}
}
```